# html converted bold or italic spanned string in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring, spannablestringbuilder

I have method in my custom EditText that makes the text **bold** or *italic*

**here is my method:**

```
public boolean changeTextStyle(TextStyle style) {
    if (isTextSelected()) {
        int startSelection = getSelectionStart();
        int endSelection = getSelectionEnd();
        SpannableString span = new SpannableString(getText().subSequence(startSelection, endSelection));
        span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        span.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(getTypeface()), 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        switch (style) {
            case BOLD_STYLE: {
                span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            break;
            case ITALIC_STYLE: {
                span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            break;
        }
        getText().replace(startSelection, endSelection, span);
        setSelection(endSelection);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When i switch **bold** text style to *italic* style or inverse every thing is fine and in the EditText it change from bold to italic but when i want to convert that text to html the problem comes and returns an html that contains both html tags bolded italic text but i want just switch between bold or italic.

**here is my converting to html method:**

```
public String getFinalText() {
    return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(Html.toHtml(getText())
            .replace("<p dir=\"ltr\">", "")
            .replace("<p dir=\"rtl\">", "")
            .replace("<u>", "")
            .replace("</u>", "")
            .replace("<p>", "")
            .replace("</p>", ""))
            .trim();
}
```

in a short way

i want this:

```
This is <b>simple</b> text
```

or

```
This is <i>simple</i> text
```

but the output is this:

```
This is <b><i>simple</i></b> text
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change these lines

```
SpannableString span = new SpannableString(getText().subSequence(startSelection, endSelection));
        span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

to

```
SpannableString span = new SpannableString(getText().subSequence(startSelection, endSelection));
final StyleSpan[] spans = span.getSpans(0, span.length(), StyleSpan.class);
for (StyleSpan styleSpan : spans) span.removeSpan(styleSpan);
```

Comment: I've tried this method before but didn't solve my problem.